# find transformation rgbdslam

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I managed to get rgbdslam up and running under ros electric and ubuntu 10.04

I'd like to know the transformation between two frames using rgbdslam.
the topics being published are of type PointCloud2 and markers.
Is this possible?

Many thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44234/find-transformation-rgbdslam/) by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2012-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After having finished processing some kinect data, you can select "Save node wide" under the Graph menu to save all the point clouds making up the model as separate pcd files.  You can then obtain the transformations between the pointclouds by selecting "Save Trajectory Estimate" under Processing.  This will save a text file containing the transformations between camera poses.

---

Originally posted by [RossK](https://answers.ros.org/users/3194/rossk/) with karma: 141 on 2012-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1